# Replacing multiple line using sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I have a text file file.log contains following text

file.log

```
ab
cd
ef
```

I want to replace "ab\ncd" with "ab\n" and the final file.log should look like this:

```
ab

ef
```

This is the sed command I am using but it couldn't recognize the newline character to match the pattern:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)\r   \(.*\)/\1\r/g' file.log
```

with 3 character space after '\r' but no change is made with this.

`\(.*\)` - This matches any character(.) followed by 0 or more (*) of the preceding character
`\r` - For newline
`\1` - Substitution for the first matching pattern. In this case, it's 'ab'

Can you help me out what's wrong with the above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, the `sed` is a stream editor, which reads line by line from the input file

So when it reads line

```
ab
```

from the input file, it doesnt know whether the line is followed by a line

```
cd
```

When it reads the line `cd` it sed will habe removed the line `ab` from the pattern space, this making the pattern invalid for the current pattern space.

**Solution**

A solution can be to read the entire file, and append them into the hold space, and then replace the hold space. As

```
$ sed -n '1h; 1!H;${g;s/ab\ncd/ab\n/g;p}' input
ab

ef
```

**What it does**

- `1h` Copies the first line into the hold space.
- `1!H` All lines excpet the first line (`1!`) appends the line to the hold space.
- `$` matches the last line, performs the commands in `{..}`
- `g` copies the contents of hold space back to pattern space
- `s/ab\ncd/ab\n/g` makes the substitution.
- `p` Prints the entire patterns space.

Answer (score 1):

Sed processes the input file line by line. So can't do like the above . You need to include `N`, so that it would append the next line into pattern space.

```
$ sed 'N;s~ab\ncd~ab\n~g' file
ab

ef
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other options:

```
perl -i -0pe 's/^ab\n\Kcd$//mg' file.log
```

which will change any such pattern in the file

If there's just one, good ol' `ed`

```
ed file.log <<END_SCRIPT
/^ab$/+1 c

.
wq
END_SCRIPT
```